# Cant access pokemon go!

Tags: pokemon-go

I recently upgraded my phone to a galaxy s7 and the sign in with Google option is not available.
I read the comment that says it's an age issue but how can that be right?
My age is 33 and the game is registered as my actual age.
I'm also still able to access the game through Google on my old galaxy j3 so this can't be the issue.

Comment: Have you added your google account to the new phone? When the game starts for the first time it will ask you for your age again, regardless of your prior registration. Set a proper age there... Don't just click it away.

Comment: Yeah, not sure how it happened but I had actually just downloaded the app for the first time on my new phone so kinda confused.

Comment: It's almost like it didn't recognize that my google account was signed in.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue like you. I guess it came from too many failed login attempts on my google account.

The solution for me was to clear Pokemon Gos App Cache in the Android settings.

Comment: Thanks, took me a bit to figure out how but I had to clear all defaults and cache.

Comment: It's all working now though

Comment: @NateWhisenant You may want to click the checkmark for this answer if this fixed it.  Thanks!